# Animation Border Setting

Tags: jquery, html, animation, jquery-animate

I want my image effect like this [link](http://platform.mediamind.com/Eyeblaster.Preview.Web/Default.aspx?previewID=H56ypDeBz7iKLWoWU5mYSoEvYe1DQb33hNfpQ9%2bTEWE6js1c5xe8aQ==&AdID=20769145&lang=en-US) and what i have done is this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Db7mC/1/) but my image effect's initial point is not correct.

How do I fix this, like it is cutting the edges and it should be inside the box just like the bag image effect.

```
    <div id="mainContainer">
                <img id="introImg" src="http://blog.room34.com/wp-content/uploads/underdog/logo.thumbnail.png"/>


        <div id="text1" style="position:absolute;">Striped Bag</div><br />
        <div id="text2" style="position:absolute;">$14</div><br />
        <div id="text3" style="position:absolute;">Sale $25</div><br />
</div>


 $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#text1").animate({ left: "+=30" }, 500);
        $("#text1").animate({ left: "-=20" }, 200);
        $("#text2").delay(300).animate({ left: "+=30" }, 500);
        $("#text2").animate({ left: "-=20" }, 200);
        $("#text3").delay(400).animate({ left: "+=30" }, 500);
        $("#text3").animate({ left: "-=20" }, 200);
     $("#introImg").animate({width: "100px"}, 1000);
    });

#mainContainer{
     background-image:url('https://secure-ds.serving-sys.com/BurstingRes/Site-8188/Type-0/5fefb401-b187-4d82-b4db-cbd2ef29cc48.gif');
    width:300px;
    height:250px;

    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative

}

#introImg{
    position:absolute;
    top:60px;
    left:170px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width:300px;
    opacity: 100;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#text1, #text2, #text3
{
     margin:60px 8px;

}

#ctaBtn{
    top:200px;
    left:25px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Db7mC/4/)**

```
#mainContainer{
     background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/ypFcNy9.gif');
    width:299px;
    height:249px;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative

}

#wrapper {
    border: 15px solid rgba(186,202,228 , 1);  
    width:300px;
    height:250px;
    position: absolute;
```

I cropped your image and removed its borders. Then, I wrapped it around with the `#wrapper` and put CSS borders. Now the image doesn't get in the way.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but my the height and width of a box increased to 330 by 282 i want it 300 by 250

Comment: or can i replace edges with the border?

Comment: Yes, you can. Let me fix it for you

Comment: yes this one is fine but i dont want to crop the image because i will be given 300x250 images with the same border but different logos as it is a ad banner so can it be something simpler for example can i replace with borders within mainContainer div are you getting me? i do not want to crop the image

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Db7mC/9/ - Ok, this one has the full image in it. The borders would work for the wrapper, it just overlaps with outlines which have a higher z-index (they are like the first layer in a graphic) and it does the magic

Comment: thanks alot this was perfect and can you please guide me how can i learn better designing techniques i am not good in front end designing but i will be converting many flash templates into html5 so do you have any good source/ books so that i can learn and start working on my tasks without wasting time

Comment: Haven't read any books so far, but took a course at my university. Personally, atttempting to do projects you consider nearly impossible for your skills and trying to answer questions on this website can go a long way. For the very basics of front-end, you can try treehouse or codecademy. I guess it all boils down to keep working and solving different problems.